# Reg query with find command and percent character in value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to determine, in a batch file, if a particular registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion /v DevicePath

in Windows contains the following value:

%SystemRoot%\inf

The code I have so far is:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion /v DevicePath | find "%SystemRoot%\inf"
```

Unfortunately %errorlevel% always returns 1 and not 0, despite several attempts at playing with the command, adding and removing %'s and escape characters. Can someone assist please? Is there a better way to determine the value of this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to escape the percent signs in batch files, double them:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion /v DevicePath |find "%%SystemRoot%%\inf"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that and although it works on its own it doesnt work in my full batch file

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion /v DevicePath | find "%%SystemRoot%%\inf"
echo %errorlevel%

I still end up with 1? Strange.

Comment: works fine for me. Is that part of your code inside a block (surrounded by `(` and `)` (for example inside a `for` loop or an `if` statement)?

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out earlier in the code I was calling a sub which set errorlevel, since found out this then renders it useless. Once removed all working with double percent signs. Thank you.